# Combobox uses TypeConverter instead of toString C#

Tags: c#, combobox, tostring, typedescriptor

I have a class with a custom `TypeDescriptor` to save and restore the data. 
In my application i use a `ComboBox` to select objects of this class. To bind the objects to the `ComboBox` i use the `DataSource` property of the `ComboBox`.

After I created the custom `TypeDescriptor` for my class, the `ComboBox` uses the `TypeDescriptor` to display the `Text` instead of the `ToString` method of my class.

How can I change the `ComboBox` to use the `ToString` method instead of the `TypeDescriptor`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using a wrapper class and populate the `ComboBox` with that?

```
private class ComboItem
{
    private MyClass theWrappedInstance;

    internal ComboItem(MyClass c)
    {
        theWrappedInstance = c;
    }

    public override ToString()
    {
        return theWrappedInstance.ToString();
    }
}
```